# Python - how to get numbers to always print in ascending order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write something that always prints numbers in ascending order.

I have something like this below, but it will always print the numbers in the order of which I have the variables. I know I am missing something here to make it so they will print in ascending order even if I toss in more numbers so they are always sorted. I am just not sure what to add in.

```
# This function compares two numbers and returns them
# in increasing order.
def order_numbers(number1, number2):
    if number2 > number1:
        return number1, number2
    else:
        return number2, number1

smaller, bigger = order_numbers(100, 99)
print(smaller, bigger)
```

I know I can write something like this `print(sorted([smaller, bigger]))` but I don't want it to print like this `[99,100]`

edit1: the same goes for print(order_numbers(smaller, bigger))

Comment: What's wrong with what you've written? Please provide a little more context info, cause what you wrote does exactly that.

Comment: If you have `numbers = [99,100]` you can print them with `print(*numbers)` in the desired way. This also works for more numbers in the list.

Comment: `sorted()` is exactly what you want here.  `print(*sorted(...))` would be one way of getting rid of the square brackets in the output that you say you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

```
def order_numbers(*args):
    numbers = list(args)
    numbers.sort()
    return numbers

# the * here unpacks the list, so you don't the the square brackets of list output.
print(*order_numbers(100,21,32,12))
# 12 21 32 100
```

OR

```
print(*sorted(number_list))
```